# Proper value for unordered_map

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, containers

I have a set of strings that I have to put into a hash table and retrieve anagrams of it. I chose the unordered_map since it's an inbuilt hash table in c++. The strings are as followings,

```
cat, act, art, tar, rat... etc..
```

Now I used the alphabetically sorted word as key and a vector of unordered words as value. This implementation takes a lot of time in insertion. Is this the best possible implementation for the requirement, or is there something less time consuming that I can use?

```
    std::tr1::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> map;
    if(map.find(sortedWord) == map.end()){
        std::vector<std::string> temp;
        temp.push_back(word);
        map.insert(make_pair(sortedWord, temp));
    }else{
        map.find(sortedWord)->second.push_back(word);
    }
```

Comment: You could start by saving the result of `find` so you only have to call it once.

Comment: Why not just use `map[sortedWord].push_back(word)`, `set`s and `map`s will automatically default construct a value if one doesn't already exist with `operator[]`.

Comment: `tr1`? Do you have access to C++11/14?

Comment: I don't have c++ 11/14 in the pc I'm currently working in, but at home I do.

Comment: Or us `unordered_multimap`.

Comment: By the way, you might test on a real C++11 implementation, in case this TR1 library is lacking in optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making that a lot more complicated than necessary, and in the process you're also slowing things down by:

- Searching for the key twice, and
- Copying a vector (with the contained word) when you have a new key. In fact, it is probably copied twice.

The following works fine with C++11, and I'm pretty sure it works the same way with tr1:

```
/* Name of map changed because I don't like to use "map"
 * or "string" as variable names */
wordMap[sortedWord].push_back(word);
```

If `sortedWord` is not present in the map, then `wordMap[sortedWord]` will insert it with a default-constructed `std::vector<std::string>>`. So whether or not `sortedWord` was present, the new word can just be appended onto the value returned by the subscript.

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer another solution, you may use C++11 `std::unordered_multiset` with customized hash algorithm and equality comparison.

The custom hash algorithm may simply combine the hash values of each characters with a commutative operation, say bitwise-xor, such that all anagrams have the same hash value.

The custom equality comparison can use `std::is_permutation` to equate all anagrams.

```
struct AnagramHash
{
    typedef std::string argument_type;
    typedef std::hash<char>::result_type result_type;

    result_type operator()(const argument_type& s) const
    {
        std::hash<char> char_hash;
        result_type result = 0;

        for (const auto& x : s)
        {
            result ^= char_hash(x);
        }

        return result;
    }
};
```

```
struct AnagramEqual
{
    typedef bool result_type;
    typedef std::string first_argument_type;
    typedef std::string second_argument_type;

    result_type operator()(const first_argument_type& lhs, const second_argument_type& rhs) const
    {
        if (lhs.size() == rhs.size())
            return std::is_permutation(std::begin(lhs), std::end(lhs), std::begin(rhs));
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

```
int main()
{
    std::unordered_multiset<std::string, AnagramHash, AnagramEqual> anagrams;

    anagrams.insert("arc");
    anagrams.insert("rac");
    anagrams.insert("car");

    anagrams.insert("H2O");
    anagrams.insert("2OH");

    auto range = anagrams.equal_range("car");
    for (auto it = range.first ; it != range.second ; ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    range = anagrams.equal_range("HO2");
    for (auto it = range.first ; it != range.second ; ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
}
```